# Can't evaluate ngClass in Angular2 based on @input

Tags: angular

I am trying to conditionally apply a class to a div based on an attribute that is coming from @input but it evaluates wrong when the same condition is evaluated against a not @input attribute (such as the test_active below) the expression works fine.

I can console.log() the value of the property in the init() function and I do get the proper value.

Here is a sample code of my Component

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-avatar',
  template: `
    <div 
      id="avatar" 
      [ngClass]="{'active': active?true:false, 'inactive': active?false:true}"
    ></div>
  `,
  styles: [
...
    `#avatar.active { border-color: #77ED00;}`,
    `#avatar.inactive {filter: grayscale(100%); border-color: red}`
  ]
})
export class AvatarComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() active;

  test_active = true;


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.active); //true
}


}
```

Comment: Works fine here: https://plnkr.co/edit/6hOyjh0PlXRr20i49xJ3?p=preview. Post the relevant code, in a plunkr, to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you pass the value as string to the input.

try

```
<app-avatar [active]="true"></app-avatar>
<app-avatar [active]="false"></app-avatar>
```

Answer (score 1):

Importantly the css classes you have listed don't have a style on their border `border-style: dashed` solid, or whatever so they make zero difference in rendering other than appending the class name to the DOM. The input is definitely being applied correctly, though.

I would also suggest you do `[ngClass]="{'active': active, 'inactive: !active}"` to save yourself a couple of unnecessary ternaries.